# Querystring to optional arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I have a querystring with a number of optional values eg.

```
/filter?location=scotland&minprice=100&maxprice=500
```

I have a filter method with a number of optional arguments

```
public List<result> Filter(
    bool isVisible = false,
    string location = null,
    int? minPrice = null,
    int? maxPrice = null,
)
```

I would like to use the querystring values as arguments on the filter method, but I can't think of a good way to do this.

The best way I can come up with is to use ?: conditions for each argument

```
var results = Filter(
   (Request.QueryString["isvisible"] != null ? Request.QueryString["isvisible"] == "true" : false)
```

and so on...

but using this method, if a particular querystring value hasn't been set, I have to pass in a default value, but I don't want to pass in a default, I want defaults to be set from within the filter method.

Is there a way to do this?  Or is there a better way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Is this ASP.Net MVC? REST API? What type of web project are we looking at? (in all cases, there is a better way to do this, but the correct answer depends on the particular web project type)

Comment: I need to use the same filter method in different parts of the project, so sometimes it would be called from a WebAPI 2 method and sometimes it would be from an MVC action.

Comment: There is default model binding in MVC and API you don't need to use `Request.QueryString`

Comment: I'm aware of that.  It doesn't solve my problem currently as for any properties in the model that aren't set from the querystring, I would still need to have defaults outside of the filter method. I'd like to keep the optional arguments on my filter method as it's a good way to call the filter from other parts of the project.  I am beginning to wonder if I need to create another method which does accept a model (which sets its own defaults), but then I am essentially setting defaults twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to map the defaults.

There are actually two "interfaces" here: the interface from the caller to the `Filter()` method and the interface from the `Filter()` method to the data source. They don't have to have the same defaults.

```
public List<Whatever> Filter(string criteria1 = null, string criteria2 = null)
{
    criteria1 = criteria1 ?? SYSTEM_DEFAULT_FOR_CRITERIA1;
    criteria2 = criteria2 ?? SYSTEM_DEFAULT_FOR_CRITERIA2;

    return _dataSource.GetData(criteria1, criteria2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it suddenly seems a lot easier with that approach!